# Powershell produce intersection of multiple Excel tables

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a few tables stored in different Excel .xlsx files. These tables all have a shared ID column.

I'm trying to create a program where, in base Powershell, I keep only the rows of each Excel whose ID is in the intersection.

The intersection is the set of IDs that are in every input Excel file.

I managed to get something working, but it is very slow. It works for a couple thousand rows, but at 100,000 rows it takes forever.

Is there a better way rather than using an external library?

The code below has:

1. An Input folder, where all of the .xlsx files of whom I want the intersection go.
2. An output folder, where each .xlsx file is filtered for rows in the intersection and renamed _processed.xlsx
3. A settings file which contains a variable `ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME` so that in the code below, $settings.ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME is the name of common the ID column in the header row of Excel table.

Code overview:

1. Count each ID from each Excel file. If the count of ID is equal to the number of Excel file, that is an ID in the intersection.
2. For each Excel, get an array of row numbers to delete, then sort the array descending and delete the rows.

How can I make this faster without external modules?

```
# ==================================== #
# Settings & Enviornment
# ==================================== #
$outPath = "$pwd\output\"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$settings_path = "$pwd\settings.txt"
$settings = Get-Content $settings_path | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData

# ==================================== #
# Delete files in output directory
# ==================================== #
Remove-Item "$pwd\output\*.*"

# ==================================== #
# Find input files
# ==================================== #
$excel_files = dir .\input | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*.xlsx"} | Select Name
$excel_files = $excel_files.Name

# ==================================== #
# Count ID from each workbook
# ==================================== #
$id_counts = @{}
foreach($file in $excel_files){
    
    write-output('Getting IDs from - ' + $file)
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$pwd\input\$file")
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
    
    # ==================================== #
    # Get ID column number from settings 
    # ==================================== #    
    $key_column = $settings.ID_COLUMN
    # get column number of header row if ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME not blank:
    if($settings.ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME -ne ''){
        $header = $ws.UsedRange.Rows[1]
        foreach($col in 1..$header.cells.count){
            if($header.Cells($col).Value() -eq $settings.ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME){                
                $key_column = $col              
            }
        }       
    }
    
    # ==================================== #
    # Get all unique IDs
    # ==================================== #
    foreach($row in $ws.UsedRange.Rows){
        # skip header row
        if($row.row -ge 2){
            $key = $row.Cells($key_column).Value()
            if($id_counts.keys -contains $key){
                $id_counts[$key] ++
            }else{ $id_counts += @{$key = 1} }
            
        }
    }
    $wb.Close($false)
}

# ==================================== #
# Get all keys in intersection 
# ==================================== #
$intersection = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ( $h in $id_counts.GetEnumerator() ){
    if($h.Value -ge $excel_files.count){
        [void]$intersection.Add($h.Name)
    }
}

# ==================================== #
# Produce output Excel with keys in intersection 
# ==================================== #

foreach($file in $excel_files){
    write-output('Removing IDs from - ' + $file)
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$pwd\input\$file")
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $delete_these = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    
    # ==================================== #
    # Get ID column number from settings 
    # ==================================== #    
    $key_column = $settings.ID_COLUMN
    # get column number of header row if ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME not blank:
    if($settings.ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME -ne ''){
        $header = $ws.UsedRange.Rows[1]
        foreach($col in 1..$header.cells.count){
            if($header.Cells($col).Value() -eq $settings.ID_COLUMN_HEADER_NAME){                
                $key_column = $col              
            }
        }       
    }
    
    # ==================================== #
    # Find rows to delete 
    # ==================================== #    
    foreach($row in $ws.UsedRange.Rows){
        # skip header row
        if($row.row -ge 2){
            $key = $row.Cells($key_column).Value()
            if($intersection -notcontains $key){
                [void]$delete_these.Add($row.row)
            }           
        }
    }
    $delete_these = $delete_these |sort -Descending
    foreach($i in $delete_these){[void]$ws.Cells.item($i, 1).EntireRow.Delete()}
    
    $output_path = $outPath + $file.Replace('.xlsx', '_processed.xlsx')
    write-output( 'Saving - ' + $file.Replace('.xlsx', '_processed.xlsx') )
    $wb.SaveAs($output_path, 51)
    $wb.Close($false)
}

# ==================================== #
# End
# ==================================== #
$Excel.quit()
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code review? You may try it here: [StackExchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No I'm asking if there is a better way to remove all rows from these Excel tables that are not in the intersection. I posted an attempt I made, but it is really slow. I know it is easy with external module but is there better way using base powershell?